# Smallest dtype that will fit all values in an array

Tags: python, numpy, types

How can I find the smallest dtype that will hold all values of an array?

For a scalar, I can use `np.min_scalar_type` to get the smallest dtype that will fit:

```py
In [32]: min_scalar_type(0)
Out[32]: dtype('uint8')

In [33]: min_scalar_type(0.1)
Out[33]: dtype('float16')

In [34]: min_scalar_type(-1)
Out[34]: dtype('int8')

In [35]: min_scalar_type(nan)
Out[35]: dtype('float16')
```

Is there an equivalent function for arrays?  The existing `min_scalar_type` just returns the dtype of the input array, which is not the smallest.

```py
In [36]: min_scalar_type([0, 0.1, -1, nan])
Out[36]: dtype('float64')  # I would like: float16

In [37]: min_scalar_type([0, 1])
Out[37]: dtype('int64')  # I would like: uint8

In [39]: min_scalar_type([1, -1])
Out[39]: dtype('int64')  # I would like: int8

In [40]: min_scalar_type([-100, 200])
Out[40]: dtype('int64')  # I would like: int16
```

This seems not entirely trivial to implement.  For example, for `[-1, 200]`, the `min_scalar_type` would be `int16`, even though `-1` fits in `int8` and 200 fits in `uint8`, so one cannot derive it from applying `min_scalar_type` to each element of the input.  I also thought of `min_scalar_type((sign(min(ar)) or 1) * max(ar))`, but that fails if all values are negative or if there are floats.  Doing this correctly needs more careful thought.

Does this already exist?

Comment: `[0, 0.1, -1, nan]` is a list.  `min_scalar_type` probably converts it to an array, e.g. `np.array([0, 0.1, -1, nan])`.  And it clearly states that `For non-scalar
array ``a``, returns the vector's dtype unmodified.`.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I understand the current behaviour is as documented, but it's not what I want :)  Anyway, I pretty much found my answer in the linked duplicate shortly after I posted this question (only downside is that I would first need to create an array with a too-large dtype, before downcasting it to a smaller dtype, but this is acceptable).